# Python 2.7 - Create pandas dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas dataframe like I have been doing for years now

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':2})
```

And there's an error right there -

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I also tried

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':1,'b':2})
```

Again same error -

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I just want to create a dataframe with columns 'a' and 'b', with values 1 and 2

```
a b
1 2
```

I'm pretty sure this is how it has always worked, but somehow it doesn't anymore. What am I missing? Is this some weird quirk of Python 2.7? Or does Pandas it refuse to work cz its a Sunday morning? Can some please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d = {'a':1,'b':2}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasnt clear. I want to create a dataframe with 2 columns 'a' and 'b'. I have edited my original question.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. But I'm very sure pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':2}) has  worked in the past. What am I missing here?

Comment: Its in the documentation as well - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html . When did it stop working?

Comment: @RohanBapat - Maybe some update of pandas? Not sure.

Comment: I dont see it in docs, do you see it? There is creating `Series` from `dict`. But maybe some time ago it was implemented, my first pandas version was 0.16.2. If used oldier version I dont know...

Comment: I just realized my mistake. In cell 10 in documentation, they are creating multiple rows, while I'm creating only a single row. Should have used a list instead.

Comment: Yes, or `tuple`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was doing wrong -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1],'B':[2]})
```

The values should be in a list. That was a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

By using `pd.Series`

```
pd.Series(d).to_frame().T
Out[74]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
```